# How can I use bootstrap datepicker in reactJs.net

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am a beginner with ReactJS. I am using ReactJs.Net (JSX) with MVC5. I want to use bootstrap date and time picker. I searched a lot but didn't find any example. I also searched at http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html. Please help with an example showing initialization of datepicker. That will help me a lot.

Comment: Are there any particular issues you encountered when trying to get it to work? What steps have you taken to debug it?

Comment: I tried to use it as suggested at [link](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker). but it showing `<DateTimeField />` not defined. It seems I  need to configure a template for using datetime picker. That's why I am looking for an example with JSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an ES6 (using [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/)) example of using Bootstrap `date-picker`.

**Declaimer**: I don't have experience with ReactJS.net, but with ReactJS

```
"use strict";

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class Calender extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date : "2016-01-15T01:06"
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="datetime-local" ref={(date) => {this.dateRef = date;}} value={this.state.date} onChange={this._onDateChange.bind(this)}/>
        );
    }

    _onDateChange(e) {
        let state = this.state;
        state['date'] = e.target.value;
        // Or (you can use below method to access component in another method)
        state['date'] = this.dateRef.value;
        this.setState(state);
    }

}

export default Calender;
```

---

*Working example:*

[image].

Reference: [ReactJS froms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)